# Read only one row of a big Excel file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, performance, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel library to read data from Excel files. My file is about 5mb, 70 columns and 20000 rows big. The code for loading the file is:

```
     $sheetnames = array('Classification');
     $excelFile = Yii::app()->basePath . '/categories/'. $region .'.xlsx';
     $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
     $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
     $objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
     $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($excelFile);
```

The Excel file has following structure:

```
Title | Id | Path | Attribute 1 | Attribute 2 | ... | Attribute 65
```

The loading of this file lasts about 6 minutes, takes too much CPU and RAM. 
Practically I need to know data of only one row with given ID. For now I iterate all rows and check for id. It's too inefficient.

So I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to load file faster? (I can not afford to use so much time, cpu and ram)
2. Is there a way to search through the file more efficient?

Comment: Be careful, PHPExcel is memory-greedy. For each cell, it takes up to 1Ko memory. So for your 20000 rows (and so 68 columns), you'll need up to 20*68Mo free RAM...

Comment: Have you tried anything like read filters? You could set a filter to read just the ID column, search in that, then read just the matching row?

Comment: @Random? 1Mo per cell?!?!? Surely you jest! My "rule of thumb" estimate is actually 1k/cell in 32-bit PHP, 1.6k/cell in 64-bit PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker I got this on my application... we were writing with PHP Excel, and had to use html instead because of this... PHPExcel stores much style data, even if not used... Maybe not the same at reading, but it worth a warn...

Comment: @Random - you're a factor of about 1000 out.... believe me, I do know a bit about how PHPExcel uses memory

Comment: @MarkBaker hmmm... yeah, I may have mixed up Ko/Mo... Edited first comment...

Comment: Hi Mark, I didn't use any filters. The loading needs about 1.6*22000*70 = 2.5GB, but it's too much for me.

Comment: @Bfcm Be aware of Ko/Kb difference...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start by using a read filter to load only the ID column:

```
/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
class SingleColumnFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
{ 
    private $requestedColumn;

    public function __construct($column) {
        $this->requestedColumn = $column;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
        if ($column == $this->requestedColumn) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
} 

/**  Create an Instance of our Read Filter  **/ 
$idColumnFilter = new SingleColumnFilter('B'); // Id is column B

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007'); 
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/ 
$objReader->setReadFilter($idColumnFilter); 
/**  Load only the column that matches our filter to PHPExcel  **/ 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

Then PHPExcel will only load data for cells in column `B`. You can then do your search through that subset of cells for the value you need (1 column and 22,000 rows is just 22,000 cells, so should be a lot closer to 35MB than 2.5GB required to load the whole file), then use a similar filter based on row number to load only the single row that you have identified.

**EDIT**

The latest 1.8.1 release of PHPExcel also has a columnIterator that should make it easier to iterate down the column looking for that specific ID value:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnIterator('B') as $column) {
    $cellIterator = $column->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
    foreach ($cellIterator as $key => $cell) {
        if ($cell->getValue == 'ABC') {
            $found = true;
            $rowId = $cell->getRow()
            break 2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**

Once you've identified the row that you want, you can use a second filter to reload the Excel file... but just that single row:

```
/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
class SingleRowFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
{ 
    private $requestedRow;

    public function __construct($row) {
        $this->requestedRow = $row;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
        if ($row == $this->requestedRow) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
} 

if ($found) {
    /**  Create an Instance of our Read Filter  **/ 
    $rowFilter = new SingleRowFilter($rowId);

    $objReader2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007'); 
    $objReader2->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objReader2->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetnames);
    /**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/ 
    $objReader2->setReadFilter($rowFilter); 
    /**  Load only the single row that matches our filter to PHPExcel  **/ 
    $objPHPExcel2 = $objReader2->load($inputFileName); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The time is anyway about 2 minutes, but I guess it's the best I can get from PHPExcel. Probably I have to change the business logic of my application to reduce the PHPExcel usage. But big thanks anyway!

Comment: Pleased that I could show you how to make it 3x faster anyway

Answer (score 2):

Dealing with exel files is a little bit difficult. Just convert them to CSV with shell exec, and perform any operations on those CSV files as much as you want.

```
$ easy_install xlsx2csv
$ xlsx2csv file.xlsx newfile.csv
```

Conversion takes less than a second.

Comment: And what about second question?

Comment: once you convert it to CSV, you will have absolutely no performance issues, regardless of the CSV size. And searching will be easy since you can just treat entire CSV file as string, and do str_pos to find line that you need, or use csv parser that php has

Comment: tested xlsx2csv on a huge file. Took less than 2 seconds to convert 20k rows. Could not measure CPU/RAM usage because it was too quick.

Comment: Tried it out. Converting xlsx->csv is taking about 30 sec, but reading data is so much faster. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speedup your program and reduce the memory consumption, you can take a look at Spout: https://github.com/box/spout.

All you need to do is:

```
$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::CSV);
$reader->open($filePath);

while ($reader->hasNextRow()) {
    $row = $reader->nextRow();
    $id = $row[1];
    // do stuff with the $id
}

$reader->close();
```

It should take 1 to 2 seconds to go through the whole file :)

Comment: Tried it out. Didn't worked for yii application. Look at details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329170/using-box-spout-3rd-party-library-in-yii-application-command