# Using box/spout 3rd party library in Yii application command

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I want to use https://github.com/box/spout library in my Yii project (in one of commands). I'm not using Composer, so I simple downloaded the extension and put in `extensions/spout/Box/`.

In my `config/main.php` I've added line

```
'import' => array(
    ...
    'application.extensions.spout.*'
),
```

And in my command I've added following lines:

```
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/extensions/spout/Box/Spout/Reader/ReaderFactory.php';
require_once Yii::app()->basePath . '/extensions/spout/Box/Spout/Common/Type.php';
```

When I'm calling `$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::CSV);` I'm getting following error:

```
PHP Error[2]: include(ReaderFactory.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    in file /srv/yii/YiiBase.php at line 421
#0 /srv/yii/YiiBase.php(421): autoload()
#1 unknown(0): autoload()
#2 /srv/dev/protected/commands/AmazonCommand.php(193): spl_autoload_call()
#3 unknown(0): AmazonCommand->actionIndex()
#4 /srv/yii/console/CConsoleCommand.php(172): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
#5 /srv/yii/console/CConsoleCommandRunner.php(67): AmazonCommand->run()
#6 /srv/yii/console/CConsoleApplication.php(91): CConsoleCommandRunner->run()
#7 /srv/yii/base/CApplication.php(169): CConsoleApplication->processRequest()
#8 /srv/yii/yiic.php(33): CConsoleApplication->run()
#9 /srv/dev/protected/yiic.php(19): require_once()
#10 /srv/dev/protected/yiic(4): require_once()
```

What I'm missing? How can I use third party library in my project?

**UPDATE**

After [that](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration) tutorial, I've moved `spout` folder in `protected/vendors` folder and changed the code following way:

```
    Yii::import('application.vendors.spout.Box.Spout.Reader.*');
    Yii::import('application.vendors.spout.Box.Spout.Common.*');
    require_once 'ReaderFactory.php';
    require_once 'Type.php';
```

Now I'm getting following error, still no clue why:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory in /srv/dev/protected/vendors/spout/B
ox/Spout/Reader/ReaderFactory.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yii 2.0 and since Spout is PSR4 compliant, you can follow this guide: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-extensions.html#installing-extensions-manually

If you are still using Yii 1.1, I am not sure what the best way to autoload your classes is. But you can still use a standard PSR4 autoloader:

**Psr4Autoloader.php**

```
namespace Autoloader;

class Psr4Autoloader
{
    /**
     * An associative array where the key is a namespace prefix and the value
     * is an array of base directories for classes in that namespace.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $prefixes = array();

    /**
     * Register loader with SPL autoloader stack.
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
    }

    /**
     * Adds a base directory for a namespace prefix.
     *
     * @param string $prefix The namespace prefix.
     * @param string $base_dir A base directory for class files in the
     * namespace.
     * @param bool $prepend If true, prepend the base directory to the stack
     * instead of appending it; this causes it to be searched first rather
     * than last.
     * @return void
     */
    public function addNamespace($prefix, $base_dir, $prepend = false)
    {
        // normalize namespace prefix
        $prefix = trim($prefix, '\\') . '\\';

        // normalize the base directory with a trailing separator
        $base_dir = rtrim($base_dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) . '/';

        // initialize the namespace prefix array
        if (isset($this->prefixes[$prefix]) === false) {
            $this->prefixes[$prefix] = array();
        }

        // retain the base directory for the namespace prefix
        if ($prepend) {
            array_unshift($this->prefixes[$prefix], $base_dir);
        } else {
            array_push($this->prefixes[$prefix], $base_dir);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads the class file for a given class name.
     *
     * @param string $class The fully-qualified class name.
     * @return mixed The mapped file name on success, or boolean false on
     * failure.
     */
    public function loadClass($class)
    {
        // the current namespace prefix
        $prefix = $class;

        // work backwards through the namespace names of the fully-qualified
        // class name to find a mapped file name
        while (false !== $pos = strrpos($prefix, '\\')) {

            // retain the trailing namespace separator in the prefix
            $prefix = substr($class, 0, $pos + 1);

            // the rest is the relative class name
            $relative_class = substr($class, $pos + 1);

            // try to load a mapped file for the prefix and relative class
            $mapped_file = $this->loadMappedFile($prefix, $relative_class);
            if ($mapped_file) {
                return $mapped_file;
            }

            // remove the trailing namespace separator for the next iteration
            // of strrpos()
            $prefix = rtrim($prefix, '\\');   
        }

        // never found a mapped file
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Load the mapped file for a namespace prefix and relative class.
     * 
     * @param string $prefix The namespace prefix.
     * @param string $relative_class The relative class name.
     * @return mixed Boolean false if no mapped file can be loaded, or the
     * name of the mapped file that was loaded.
     */
    protected function loadMappedFile($prefix, $relative_class)
    {
        // are there any base directories for this namespace prefix?
        if (isset($this->prefixes[$prefix]) === false) {
            return false;
        }

        // look through base directories for this namespace prefix
        foreach ($this->prefixes[$prefix] as $base_dir) {

            // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory,
            // replace namespace separators with directory separators
            // in the relative class name, append with .php
            $file = $base_dir
                  . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class)
                  . '.php';

            // if the mapped file exists, require it
            if ($this->requireFile($file)) {
                // yes, we're done
                return $file;
            }
        }

        // never found it
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * If a file exists, require it from the file system.
     * 
     * @param string $file The file to require.
     * @return bool True if the file exists, false if not.
     */
    protected function requireFile($file)
    {
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then add this code to your root file or wherever you think it's the most appropriate (just make sure the path for "require_once" is correct):

**autoload.php**

```
require_once "Psr4Autoloader.php";

$loader = new \Autoloader\Psr4Autoloader;
$loader->register();
$loader->addNamespace('Box\Spout', 'vendor/box/spout/src/Spout');
```

You should now be able to use Spout!