# Yii console app - Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found

Tags: web-applications, yii, console-application, guzzle

My configs:

## /trunk/common/extensions/Api/Api.php

## /trunk/vendor/guzzle

## webapp config: /trunk/members/config/main.php

```
...
'components' => array(
        'api' => array(
            'class' => 'common.extensions.Api.Api'
        )
        ...
)
...
```

## console config: /trunk/console/config/main.php

```
...
'components' => array(
        'api' => array(
            'class' => 'common.extensions.Api.Api'
        )
        ...
)
...
```

## Client.php

namespace Guzzle\Http;

---

Guzzle was installed via composer.

When I run the API request via webapp, everything is ok

When I run the API via console app, following error is thrown
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found in /var/www/core/trunk/common/extensions/Api/Api.php on line 20

Any ideas what to do next? Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

Api.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // <-- I had to include this line so the class to be loaded
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
```

Comment: Wanted to expand my answer to this, didn't know Guzzle use autoload.

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that file `Guzzle/Http/Client.php` exist (I guess it is, because you can use the extension in webapp).

Second, at the beginning of a controller class file, insert following lines:

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('Guzzle/Http/Client.php');
```

**Using namespaced 3rd-Party Libraries**

In order to use namespaced library that follows PSR-0 (such as Zend Framework 2 or Symfony2) you need to register its root as path alias.

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('Guzzle',Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.vendors.Guzzle'));
```

In the code above the name of the alias we've defined should match the first namespace part used in the library.

If that all won't work it could be a refer for a very strange Yii bug with console applications (had also the same problem):

Question in Larry Ullmans Forum:

http://www.larryullman.com/forums/index.php?/topic/3392-console-application-php-fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-class/

My problem:
[Using box/spout 3rd party library in Yii application command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30329170/using-box-spout-3rd-party-library-in-yii-application-command)

**Using 3rd-Party Autoloaders**

Some 3rd-Party libraries (for example PHPUnit) use their own class autoloaders, which perform class file inclusion by rules, which are different from the ones used in Yii autoloader.

In order to avoid such problem make sure any 3rd-party class autoloaders are registered before the Yii autoloader.

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); // register 3rd-party autoloader
require_once('/path/to/framework/yii.php'); // register Yii autoloader
```

If 3rd-party class autoloader is coming as separated function or method, you may use `Yii::registerAutoloader()` method to register it. In this case Yii will prepend it before own autoloader automatically.

```
require_once('/path/to/framework/yii.php'); // register Yii autoloader
...
Yii::registerAutoloader(array('SomeLibrary','autoload')); // register 3rd-party autoloader
...
```

[(c) source](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/extension.integration)

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

I included the class in Api.php like this. For webapp it works, so I guess this is not the problem.

use Guzzle\Http\Client;

Also imported the libs into main.php

'import' => array(
    'application.vendor.guzzle.*',
...